# Make a title of the field goes over the field: asp MVC/Razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, model-view-controller

I want when I enters information in the field, then the title of the field goes over the field.

Here is my code:

so in the field we have the text "FIRSTNAME", my purpose is when i enters information in this field, the text "FIRSTNAME" goes over the field.

And as long as the client has nothing to enter in a field, then the title remains in the field.

I search a lot if there is a trick to add in TextBoxFor to do that but i didn't find!

[state 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlvfa.jpg).
 [state 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBmoW.jpg).

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @placeholder = "FIRSTNAME", @class = "adresse-input"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use js for this. First wrap your textbox and corresponding label inside a div:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <label for="FirstName">FIRSTNAME</label>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @placeholder = "FIRSTNAME",
  @class = "adresse-input"})
</div>
```

Then define a couple of CSS classes that will make label float:

```
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  margin:25px;
}
label {
  position:absolute;
  top:-13px;
  left:0;
  font-size:11px;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
  opacity:0;
}
label.above {
  top:-20px;
  opacity:1;
}
```

And finally add JavaScript to apply classes dynamically when user fills in the field:

```
$(function(){
  $("input").on("keyup",function(){
    $(this).prev("label").toggleClass("above", this.value !== "");
  });
});
```

I also prepared a sample fiddle to show you the final behavior: [Floating label](https://jsfiddle.net/Lesmian/2fvbo5pt/)

**EDIT**
As per your request. If you want to additionally move label above input if focus in on the field (no matter if its empty or not) then js code would be slightly different:

```
$(function(){
  $("input").on("focus",function(){
    $(this).prev("label").addClass("above");
    $(this).attr("placeholder", "");
  }).on("blur",function(){
    var label = $(this).prev("label");
    label.removeClass("above");
    $(this).attr("placeholder", label.text());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we add this property that:
if the customer enters into the field, the title passes over the field, if it comes out of the field without having nothing entered, then the title goes back inside the field.

Comment: Hej, I've edited my answer, so you can check it out.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i want !! thanks a lot,@Lesmian